# Output converted text horizontally including spaces (caesar cipher)

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path phrase.xml
$offset = $xml.assignment.caesar_cipher.offset
$cipher = $xml.assignment.caesar_cipher.cipher

$translation = [ordered]@{}
$alpha = @('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M',`
             'N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z')
For ($i=0; $i -lt 26; $i++)
{
    $translation[$alpha[((((-$i + $offset) % 26) + 26) % 26)]] = $alpha[$i]
}
$cipher_int = $cipher.ToCharArray() | %{$translation["$_"]}
$deciphered = [string[]]$cipher_int
$deciphered
-join [array]$deciphered
```

I get the phrase to translate but, $deciphered outputs it vertically with each letter on a new line, and when I did -join [array] it output the whole phrase on 1 line horizontally but it got rid of the spaces between words so it was one long word.
I'm trying to output the phrase on one line but also keep the spaces.

example phrase all jumbled up tho: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

```
$deciphered =  
T  
h  
e  
...  

[array]$deciphered = Thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog
```

Comment: I don’t see anything in your script that handles spaces. If I recall correctly there are 3 possible different ASCII white space characters that my need to be handled, but check the character code of the spaces being input from the xml. Since I can’t see what’s in the original variable, I can’t propose an exact solution. But I don’t think you’re getting spaces because they are being lost in the conversion itself. I’d recommend stepping through and monitoring how spaces are handled, it should be pretty obvious at which line they are lost.

Comment: It's impossible to propose an answer without having the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Your `translation` hash table does not have an entry for space.

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path phrase.xml
$offset = $xml.assignment.caesar_cipher.offset
$cipher = $xml.assignment.caesar_cipher.cipher

$translation = [ordered]@{}
$upperCase = @('A'..'Z')
$lowerCase = @('a'..'z')
For ($i=0; $i -lt 26; $i++)
{
    $translation[[char]$upperCase[((((-$i + $offset) % 26) + 26) % 26)]] = [char]$upperCase[$i]
    $translation[[char]$lowerCase[((((-$i + $offset) % 26) + 26) % 26)]] = [char]$lowerCase[$i]
}
$translation[[char]' '] = [char]' '

$deciphered = -join $translation[$cipher.ToCharArray()]
```

---

#### EDIT

The range operator (`..`) supports characters only in PowerShell 6 and later.

Comment: `'A'..'Z'` only works on PS Core, you should clarify that. `65..90 | ForEach-Object { [char]$_ }` for Windows Powerhsell.

Comment: Thanks @SantiagoSquarzon, I was not aware.